# How to make JavaScript execute after page load?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events, pageload

I'm executing an external script, using a `<script>` inside `<head>`.

Now since the script executes **before** the page has loaded, I can't access the `<body>`, among other things. I'd like to execute some JavaScript after the document has been "loaded" (HTML fully downloaded and in-RAM). Are there any events that I can hook onto when my script executes, that will get triggered on page load?

Comment: For cases where "right after page load" is still too early: [Run JavaScript after all window.onload scripts have completed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1593527/8910547).

Answer (score 1211, accepted):

These solutions will work:

As mentioned in comments use [defer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer):

```
<script src="deferMe.js" defer></script>
```

or

```
<body onload="script();">
```

or

```
document.onload = function ...
```

or even

```
window.onload = function ...
```

Notes

- `window.onload` is [considered more standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807878/javascript-that-executes-after-page-load#comment617710_807891) than `document.onload`
- Using `defer` or `window.onload` is [unobstrusive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).

Comment: What is the difference between <body onload="script();"> and document.onload=function ... ?

Comment: @mentoliptus: `document.onload=` is non obtrusive  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript

Comment: script in the html ...no no no $(function() { code here }); <- javascript.js can be placed in head and will load after DOM

Comment: @gerdi OP didn't mention anything about jQuery. I also gave an unobtrusive option in my answer.

Comment: @gerdi No problem, I edited my answer to show the difference more clearly

Comment: For some reason in my case $(window).load(function(){ /*code here*/ }) worked

Comment: `window.onload = function` worked in my case. I saw people answering `$(document).ready(function()` for the same question on some other forums, but that doesn't work for me!

Comment: For completeness, would you add the `jQuery` syntax for document load?

Comment: document.onload didn't work for me.  I found this post w/ the same issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5135638/why-does-window-onload-work-while-document-onload-doesnt.  Doesn't seem like document.onload is an option.

Comment: I prefer the first approach, which I find it clearer - esp. when using aspx with only limited on-page javascript.

Comment: `document.onload` doesnt work in Google Chrome, when used in a separate `index.js` script file. `window.onload` *does* work. (Chrome  71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (64-bit))

Comment: *ALL* of these options are much *later* than necessary, given the goal of running javascript once DOM is ready to be manipulated. Two better choices for that goal:  1) Use `defer` attribute on javascript link in head.  2) move any javascript that accesses DOM to bottom of page, immediately before `</body>`.

Comment: Using onload functions are bad style in my eyes, because it just refers to the last assigned function. Look at  the answer of DevWL https://stackoverflow.com/a/36096571/11323907.

Comment: I want my function to be called after a different function which is already listening for the load event. Is there something like a postLoad event?

Comment: Overwriting `window.onload` is generally a bad practice, as it doesn't allow multiple functions in it. It could overwrite a potentially critical component of a legacy script. I would use this instead, as it can handle multiple listeners: `window.addEventListener("load", function() { myScript() }) `

Comment: @Metalhead This is what I mean. It is a terrible programming practice.

Answer (score 490):

## Triggering scripts in the right moment

A quick overview on how to load / run the script at the moment in which they intend to be loaded / executed.

### Using "defer"

```
<script src="script.js" defer></script>
```

Using defer will trigger after domInteractive (document.readyState = "interactive") and just before "DOMContentLoaded" Event is triggered. If you need to execute the script after all resources (images, scripts) are loaded use "load" event or target one of the document.readyState states. Read further down for more information about those events / states, as well as async and defer attributes corresponding to script fetching and execution timing.

> This Boolean attribute is set to indicate to a browser that the script
> is meant to be executed after the document has been parsed, but before
> firing DOMContentLoaded.
>
> Scripts with the defer attribute will prevent the DOMContentLoaded
> event from firing until the script has loaded and finished evaluating.

Resource: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attributes

* See the images at the bottom for feather explanation.

### Event Listeners - Keep in mind that loading of the page has more, than one event:

#### "DOMContentLoaded"

This event is fired when the *initial HTML document has been completely loaded and parsed*, without waiting for style sheets, images, and subframes to finish loading. At this stage you could programmatically optimize loading of images and CSS based on user device or bandwidth speed.

Executes after DOM is loaded (before images and CSS):

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    //....
});
```

> Note: Synchronous JavaScript pauses parsing of the DOM.
> If you want the DOM to get parsed as fast as possible after the user requested the page, you could **turn your JavaScript asynchronous** and [optimize loading of style sheets](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeCSSDelivery)

#### "load"

A very different event, **load**, should only be used to detect a *fully-loaded page*. It is an incredibly popular mistake to use load where DOMContentLoaded would be much more appropriate, so be cautious.

Executes after everything is loaded and parsed:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    // ....
});
```

---

*MDN Resources:*
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load

*MDN list of all events:*
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events

### Event Listeners with readyStates - Alternative solution (readystatechange):

You can also track document.readystatechange states to trigger script execution.

```
// Place in header (do not use async or defer)
document.addEventListener('readystatechange', event => {
  switch (document.readyState) {
    case "loading":
      console.log("document.readyState: ", document.readyState,
       `- The document is still loading.`
       );
      break;
    case "interactive":
      console.log("document.readyState: ", document.readyState, 
        `- The document has finished loading DOM. `,
        `- "DOMContentLoaded" event`
        );
      break;
    case "complete":
      console.log("document.readyState: ", document.readyState, 
        `- The page DOM with Sub-resources are now fully loaded. `,
        `- "load" event`
        );
      break;
  }
});
```

MDN Resources: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState

### Where to place your script (with & without async/defer)?

This is also very important to know where to place your script and how it positions in HTML as well as parameters like defer and async will affects script fetching, execution and HTML blocking.

* On the image below the yellow label “Ready” indicates the moment of ending loading HTML DOM. Then it fires: document.readyState = "interactive" >>> defered scripts >>> DOMContentLoaded event (it's sequential);

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

If your script uses **async** or **defer** read this: https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-async-defer/

### And if all of the above points are still to early...

What if you need your script to run *after* other scripts are run, including those scheduled to run at the very end (e.g. those scheduled for the "load" event)? See [Run JavaScript after all window.onload scripts have completed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1593527/8910547)

What if you need to make sure your script runs *after* some other script, regardless of when it is run? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74956907/8910547) to the above question has that covered too.

Comment: @Peter pretty sure this stands alone probably best if it in the bottom of your javascript files so it executes last

Comment: This is the most completed answer. onload is after, but people don't realize this at first.

Comment: Re *asynchronous javascript*:  to clarify, there are two choices for scripts that don't immediately run.  Of those, **defer** is usually preferable to **async** - because *defer* won't interrupt html parsing/rendering - and when it runs, DOM is guaranteed to be ready. [Efficiently load JavaScript with defer and async](https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-async-defer/#blocking-rendering).

Comment: +1 I tried `window.onload = ...` thinking that my script would wait until everything was fully downloaded before running but it seems `window.onload` actually behaves like `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ...`, whereas the `window.addEventListener("load", ...` really does wait for everything to be fully downloaded. I would have thought that `window.onload` should be equivalent to `window.addEventListener("load", ...` rather than `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ...` ?? I got the same result in Chrome and FF.

Comment: @DevWL, I think you meant "defer"... because "async" can still execute before the all the html loads.

Comment: @RayLoveless yes, I meant defer. So JavaScript pauses render of the DOM there for, the best way would be to place it at the bottom of the page or to load JavaScript script with defer attribute (placed in the header). Thanks

Answer (score 212):

Reasonably portable, non-framework way of having your script set a function to run at load time:

```
if(window.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent('onload', yourFunctionName);
} else {
    if(window.onload) {
        var curronload = window.onload;
        var newonload = function(evt) {
            curronload(evt);
            yourFunctionName(evt);
        };
        window.onload = newonload;
    } else {
        window.onload = yourFunctionName;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for posting almost exactly what I had to come up with 6 months ago. Code like this can be necessary if other frameworks and code that you have no control over are adding onload events and you want to as well without wiping out the other onload events. I included my implementation as a function and it required var newonload = function(evt) { curronload(evt); newOnload(evt); } because for some reason the framework I am using requires an event to be passed to the onload event.

Comment: I just discovered in testing that the code as written results in handlers being fired in an undefined order when attached with attachEvent(). If order-of-handler-execution is important you may want to leave out the window.attachEvent branch.

Comment: So this will add this Function as an ADDITIONAL function to run OnLoad, correct? (rather than replacing an existing onload event)

Comment: @ClayNichols: Correct.

Comment: Good solution, but now outdated: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/attachEvent

Comment: Reminder: Don't modify objects that aren't yours, specially globals... see Renan's link

Answer (score 137):

You can put a "onload" attribute inside the body

```
...<body onload="myFunction()">...
```

Or if you are using jQuery, you can do

```
$(document).ready(function(){ /*code here*/ }) 

or 

$(window).load(function(){ /*code here*/ })
```

I hope it answer your question.

Note that the $(window).load will execute after the document is rendered on your page.

Answer (score 81):

If the scripts are loaded within the `<head>` of the document, then it's possible use the `defer` attribute in script tag.

**Example:**

```
<script src="demo_defer.js" defer></script>
```

**From [https://developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script):**

> **defer**
>
> This Boolean attribute is set to indicate to a browser that the script
>   is meant to be executed after the document has been parsed, but before
>   firing DOMContentLoaded.
>
> *This attribute must not be used if the src
>   attribute is absent (i.e. for inline scripts), in this case it would
>   have no effect.*
>
> To achieve a similar effect for dynamically inserted scripts use
>   async=false instead. Scripts with the defer attribute will execute in
>   the order in which they appear in the document.

Comment: I love this solution, because not need any javascript code, but only need is one html attribute <3

Comment: This is wrong fundamentally. Defer does not prevent execution post page onload. Both defer and async scripts are loaded before page load, instead, improves the "domInteraction" time.

Comment: @Akansh the OP just wanted a way to ensure the DOM had loaded before their script executes. Defer does this, it's literally written in the documentation snippet I shared in my answer.

Comment: It looks like you can make inline script load after page load using async false? "To achieve a similar effect for dynamically inserted scripts use async=false instead. - This Boolean attribute is set to indicate to a browser that the script is meant to be executed after the document has been parsed, but before firing DOMContentLoaded."

Answer (score 35):

Here's a script based on deferred js loading after the page is loaded,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function downloadJSAtOnload() {
      var element = document.createElement("script");
      element.src = "deferredfunctions.js";
      document.body.appendChild(element);
  }

  if (window.addEventListener)
      window.addEventListener("load", downloadJSAtOnload, false);
  else if (window.attachEvent)
      window.attachEvent("onload", downloadJSAtOnload);
  else window.onload = downloadJSAtOnload;
</script>
```

**Where do I place this?**

> Paste code in your HTML just before the `</body>` tag (near the bottom of your HTML file).

**What does it do?**

> This code says wait for the entire document to load, then load the
>    external file `deferredfunctions.js`.

Here's an example of the above code - [Defer Rendering of JS](https://varvy.com/pagespeed/defer/defer-example-solved.html)

I wrote this based on [defered loading of javascript](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/BlockingJS#deferJS) pagespeed google concept and also sourced from this article [Defer loading javascript](https://varvy.com/pagespeed/defer-loading-javascript.html)

Comment: I think this solution, combined with the answer of `chaos` user (https://stackoverflow.com/a/807997/10712525), will be the best thing that u can do.

Answer (score 23):

Look at hooking `document.onload` or in jQuery `$(document).load(...)`.

Comment: Is this event reliable? (Cross browser.. IE6+ FF2+ etc)

Comment: Yes this is cross-browser, standard DOM.

Comment: It's actually window.onload that's more standard, not document.onload. AFAIK

Comment: Is `onload` called before or after all resources (such as fonts and images) are loaded and properly visually updated?

Answer (score 23):

## JavaScript

```
document.addEventListener('readystatechange', event => { 

    // When HTML/DOM elements are ready:
    if (event.target.readyState === "interactive") {   //does same as:  ..addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded"..
        alert("hi 1");
    }

    // When window loaded ( external resources are loaded too- `css`,`src`, etc...) 
    if (event.target.readyState === "complete") {
        alert("hi 2");
    }
});
```

## same for jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {   //same as: $(function() { 
     alert("hi 1");
});

$(window).load(function() {
     alert("hi 2");
});
```

---

**NOTE:** - Don't use the below markup ( because it overwrites other same-kind declarations ) :

```
document.onreadystatechange = ...
```

Answer (score 14):

I find sometimes on more complex pages that not all the elements have loaded by the time window.onload is fired. If that's the case, add setTimeout before your function to delay is a moment. It's not elegant but it's a simple hack that renders well.

```
window.onload = function(){ doSomethingCool(); };
```

becomes...

```
window.onload = function(){ setTimeout( function(){ doSomethingCool(); }, 1000); };
```

Answer (score 11):

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aash1010/w9s0pe96/)** on `<body onload="myFunction()">`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   function myFunction(){
    alert("Page is loaded");
   }
  </script>
 </head>

 <body onload="myFunction()">
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
 </body>    
</html>
```

Answer (score 11):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function downloadJSAtOnload() {
   var element = document.createElement("script");
   element.src = "defer.js";
   document.body.appendChild(element);
  }
  if (window.addEventListener)
   window.addEventListener("load", downloadJSAtOnload, false);
  else if (window.attachEvent)
   window.attachEvent("onload", downloadJSAtOnload);
  else window.onload = downloadJSAtOnload;
</script>
```

http://www.feedthebot.com/pagespeed/defer-loading-javascript.html

Answer (score 9):

If you are using jQuery,

`$(function() {...});`

is equivalent to

`$(document).ready(function () { })`

or another short hand:

`$().ready(function () { })`

See [What event does JQuery $function() fire on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908724/what-event-does-jquery-function-fire-on) and https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 8):

```
document.onreadystatechange = function(){
     if(document.readyState === 'complete'){
         /*code here*/
     }
}
```

look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536957(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: one-line:  document.onload = function() { ... }

Answer (score 7):

Just define `<body onload="aFunction()">` that will be called after the page has been loaded. Your code in the script is than enclosed by `aFunction() { }`.

Answer (score 4):

```
<body onload="myFunction()">
```

This code works well.

But `window.onload` method has various dependencies. So it may not work all the time.

Answer (score 4):

## Comparison

In below snippet I collect choosen methods and show their sequence. Remarks

- the `document.onload` (X) is not supported by any modern browser (event is never [fired](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5135638/860099))
- if you use `<body onload="bodyOnLoad()">` (F) and at the same time `window.onload` (E) then only first one will be executed (because it override second one)
- event handler given in `<body onload="...">` (F)  is wrapped by additional `onload` function
- `document.onreadystatechange` (D) not override `document .addEventListener('readystatechange'...)` (C) probably cecasue `onXYZevent-like` methods are independent than `addEventListener` queues (which allows add multiple listeners). Probably nothing happens between execution this two handlers.
- all scripts write their timestamp in console - but scripts which also have access to `div` write their timestamps also in body (click "Full Page" link after script execution to see it).
- solutions `readystatechange` (C,D) are executed multiple times by browser but for different document states:

  - *loading* - the document is loading (no fired in snippet)
  - *interactive* - the document is parsed, fired before `DOMContentLoaded`
  - *complete* - the document and resources are loaded, fired before `body/window onload`

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    // solution A
    console.log(`[timestamp: ${Date.now()}] A: Head script`);
    
    // solution B
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
      print(`[timestamp: ${Date.now()}] B: DOMContentLoaded`);
    });

    // solution C
    document.addEventListener('readystatechange', () => {
      print(`[timestamp: ${Date.now()}] C: ReadyState: ${document.readyState}`);
    });
   
    // solution D
    document.onreadystatechange = s=> {print(`[timestamp: ${Date.now()}] D: document.onreadystatechange ReadyState: ${document.readyState}`)};
    
    // solution E (never executed)
    window.onload = () => {
      print(`E: <body onload="..."> override this handler`);
    };

    // solution F
    function bodyOnLoad() {
      print(`[timestamp: ${Date.now()}] F: <body onload='...'>`);      
      infoAboutOnLoad(); // additional info
    }
    
    // solution X
    document.onload = () => {print(`document.onload is never fired`)};



    // HELPERS

    function print(txt) { 
      console.log(txt);
      if(mydiv) mydiv.innerHTML += txt.replace('<','&lt;').replace('>','&gt;') + '<br>';
    }
    
    function infoAboutOnLoad() {
      console.log("window.onload (after  override):", (''+document.body.onload).replace(/\s+/g,' '));
      console.log(`body.onload==window.onload --> ${document.body.onload==window.onload}`);
    }
            
    console.log("window.onload (before override):", (''+document.body.onload).replace(/\s+/g,' '));

  </script>
</head>

<body onload="bodyOnLoad()">
  <div id="mydiv"></div>

  <!-- this script must te at the bottom of <body> -->
  <script>
    // solution G
    print(`[timestamp: ${Date.now()}] G: <body> bottom script`);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a very good documentation on How to [detect if document has loaded](http://code.askmein.com/how-to-detect-if-document-has-loaded-using-javascript-code/) using Javascript or Jquery.

Using the native Javascript this can be achieved

```
if (document.readyState === "complete") {
 init();
 }
```

This can also be done inside the interval

```
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    if(document.readyState === 'complete') {
        clearInterval(interval);
        init();
    }    
}, 100);
```

[Eg By Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState)

```
switch (document.readyState) {
  case "loading":
    // The document is still loading.
    break;
  case "interactive":
    // The document has finished loading. We can now access the DOM elements.
    var span = document.createElement("span");
    span.textContent = "A <span> element.";
    document.body.appendChild(span);
    break;
  case "complete":
    // The page is fully loaded.
    console.log("Page is loaded completely");
    break;
}
```

Using Jquery
To check only if DOM is ready

```
// A $( document ).ready() block.
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
});
```

To check if all resources are loaded use window.load

```
 $( window ).load(function() {
        console.log( "window loaded" );
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this code with jQuery library, this would work perfectly fine.

```js
$(window).bind("load", function() { 

  // your javascript event

});
```

Comment: Add some description here

Answer (score 3):

```
$(window).on("load", function(){ ... });
```

[.ready()](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) works best for me.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ ... });
```

[.load()](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/#load-handler) will work, but it won't wait till the page is loaded.

```
jQuery(window).load(function () { ... });
```

Doesn't work for me, breaks the next-to inline script. I am also using jQuery 3.2.1 along with some other jQuery forks.

To hide my websites loading overlay, I use the following:

```
<script>
$(window).on("load", function(){
$('.loading-page').delay(3000).fadeOut(250);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write a function on a specific script file and call it in to your body element using onload attribute.

Exemple:

```
<script>
  afterPageLoad() {
   //your code here
}
</script>
```

Now call your script into your html page using script tag:

```
<script src="afterload.js"></script>
```

into your body element; add onload attribute like this:

```
<body onload="afterPageLoad();">
```

Comment: Please reconsider you rollback which undid a helpful edit. Getting the readability of your posts improved by other users should be considered a good thing.

Answer (score 1):

As Daniel says, you could use document.onload.

The various javascript frameworks hwoever (jQuery, Mootools, etc.) use a custom event 'domready', which I guess must be more effective.  If you're developing with javascript, I'd highly recommend exploiting a framework, they massively increase your productivity.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [YUI library](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui) (I love it):

```
YAHOO.util.Event.onDOMReady(function(){
    //your code
});
```

Portable and beautiful! However, if you don't use YUI for other stuff (see its doc) I would say that it's not worth to use it.

N.B. : to use this code you need to import 2 scripts

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.7.0/build/yahoo/yahoo-min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.7.0/build/event/event-min.js" ></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

i can catch page load by this code

```
<script>
console.log("logger saber");

window.onload = (event) => {
  console.log('page is fully loaded');
document.getElementById("tafahomNameId_78ec7c44-beab-40de-9326-095f474519f4_$LookupField").value = 1;;
};

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

My advise use `asnyc` attribute for script tag thats help you to load the external scripts after page load

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="a.js" async></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="b.js" async></script>
```

Comment: According to [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_async.asp), _If async is present: The script is executed asynchronously with the rest of the page (the script will be executed while the page continues the parsing)_.  Perhaps you meant `defer` instead, like @Daniel Price mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).bind("load", function() { 

// your javascript event here

});
</script>
```

Comment: This answer depends on jquery

Answer (score 0):

In this example, the DOMContentLoaded event is used to ensure that the JavaScript code inside the event listener is executed only after the HTML document has been completely loaded and parsed. This is useful when you want to manipulate the DOM or perform other actions that rely on the existence of HTML elements.

Replace the comment  with your actual HTML content, and the JavaScript code inside the event listener will be executed once the document is fully loaded.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document Load Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <!-- Your HTML content goes here -->
    
    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            // Your JavaScript code to be executed after the document is fully loaded
            console.log('Document is fully loaded');
            
            // You can put your other JavaScript code here
        });
    </script>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```