# Get height of image when refreshing

Tags: jquery, html, dimensions

I'm trying to get the height of an image with jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert($('#image').height());
})
```

Very basic. However I'm confused.
If I press F5 I get the following result:
Firefox: 383px
IE 8: 30px
Chrome: 0px

If I go to the page via a link:
Firefox: 383px
IE 8: 383px
Chrome: 383px

383 is obviously the correct value. But why do I get the wrong value upon refresh?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`document.ready` fires after the DOM has loaded, but not necessarily after the images and CSS have loaded. If you run that code on `window.onload`, you should get consistent results across the browsers.

Try using jQuery's `load` handler instead:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    alert($('#image').height());
})
```

Comment: Very nice! I guess the picture was cached when I followed a link and therefore it was able to determine size in all browsers.

Answer (score 3):

Try waiting until the image is completely loaded

```
    var img = document.getElementById("image");
    img.onload = function () {
    alert($('#image').height());
    };
```

Comment: IE has some known issues with image.onload: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/198892/img-onload-doesnt-work-well-in-ie7

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#image').bind("load", function() {
       alert($('#image').height());
    });

})
```