# Javascript: Images loading too slowly

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I have an array of images that I create dialogs from.

I need to know the width of the image to make that the width of the dialog.

```
//Used to get dimensions of image
var image = new Image();

//Set Image
image.src = ImageArray[currentImageVal + direction].src;

//Get direction to move photos
switch (direction) {
    case 1:
        //Set current val
        currentImageVal = currentImageVal + 1;
        break;
    case -1:
        //Set current val
        currentImageVal = currentImageVal - 1;
        break;
}

//Set image
$('DialogImagesBig').attr('src', ImageArray[currentImageVal].src);
//Set new current image
CurrentDialogImage = ImageArray[currentImageVal].src;

console.log(image.src);
console.log(image.width);

//Check if it is less than 450
if (image.width < 450) {
    //Adjust css
    $('.ui-dialog').css('width', image.width + 50);
    //Edit dialog position
    $('.ImageDialogDiv').dialog("option", "position", 'center');
} else {
    //Normal width
    $('.ui-dialog').css('width', '500');
    //Edit dialog position
    $('.ImageDialogDiv').dialog("option", "position", 'center');
}
```

The problem is that more times then not the image will not load up in time (the `console.log(image.width)` will equal 0 but `console.log(image.src)` will be correct).

Is there a way for me to pause the rest of the script until the image is loaded (everything after `image.src`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can attach rest of the code in `img.onload` function. This will get called when the image gets loaded.

Make sure you set the `image.src` after this function declaration.

```
image.onload = function () {
    if (image.width < 450) {
        //Adjust css
        $('.ui-dialog').css('width', image.width + 50);
        //Edit dialog position
        $('.ImageDialogDiv').dialog("option", "position", 'center');
    } else {
        //Normal width
        $('.ui-dialog').css('width', '500');
        //Edit dialog position
        $('.ImageDialogDiv').dialog("option", "position", 'center');
    }
}

image.src = ImageArray[currentImageVal + direction].src;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using onload event may be problematic with ie, in some circumstances - see comments here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197055(v=vs.85).aspx -- even if the image is created in code, if it's already cached, it may not fire. This may only apply to IE6-7.

So in addition to doing this, you should check first to see if it's finished loading before binding the event using the `naturalWidth` and `complete` (for old IE) properties. `naturalWidth` (and height) will be undefined until the image has loaded.

I can conceive of a race condition if you check first to see if it's loaded, then if not, bind the "onload" event, but between these two actions, the image finishes loading. I am not sure if this is possible given JS's single-threaded nature, but since images are loaded asynchronously, perhaps it is.

In a project where I had a similar problem, I would just check for whether the image was loaded or not, and if not, set a timeout to call the function again, so it would keep trying until it was loaded. This would avoid any possible race condition.

Comment: This is why you need to set the `src` property afterwards.

Comment: According to the comments from that page, in IE7 at least, it doesn't matter, it won't fire if it's been cached by the browser.

Comment: See this for a workaround for IE7: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/198892/img-onload-doesnt-work-well-in-ie7

Comment: One of the answers is pretty much the same thing I was suggesting (test & use a timeout), is that what you mean? The accepted one is not relevant.

Comment: Yup! I was referring to the YUI one