# Adding div dynamically, but images very slow to load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I'm creating divs dynamically based on ajax callbacks. Each div contains a single png image:

```
var myDiv = "<div class='myClass' id='divid'>" + 
            "<img id='newDiagDivId' src='images/approved-icon.png'>" + 
            "<div style='display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;'>blah</div>" + 
            "</div>";
```

...here's how I add it:

```
$(myDiv).hide().appendTo( divContainer).fadeIn( 100);
```

The div displays correctly formatted, but the png image takes about 5-10s to show up. It's a tiny image, just 2kb, hosted locally from the app itself. The issue occurs on FF, Chrome, and IE, there's literally no difference in behavior.

The page handles about 2-3 ajax callbacks per second in "rapid fire" fashion, spitting out these divs for each callback, I don't have a slow machine, so I don't suspect the browser falling behind while loading the images.

Is there anything I can do to force the images to load faster or, immediately upon the div being added to the dom?

Comment: Did you check it in other browsers?

Comment: It's the same deal in FF, Chrome, and IE.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [Javascript: Images loading too slowly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524935/javascript-images-loading-too-slowly)

Comment: What is the variable `divContainer` set to?

Comment: @StefanDunn Just another simple `div` with class and id attributes only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I'm answering my own question yet again...

Decided to preload images in the DOM based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7311452/791406), works in FF, Chrome, IE!

```
$(window).load(
      function() { 
          preload(['images/approved-icon.png','images/denied-icon.png'])});

function preload(arrayOfImages) {
    $(arrayOfImages).each(function () {
        $('<img />').attr('src',this).appendTo('body').css('display','none');
    });
}
```