# Javascript Image onload function in IE

Tags: javascript

I am trying to place the image in the middle of the screen but in `IE` it's not working

here is my sample code.

```
function showMap(event, url, element)
{
        var map_container = $('map_container'),
        viewport = document.viewport.getDimensions(),
        offset = $(element).viewportOffset(),
        top = offset.top + getScrollTop() + $(element).getHeight() + 10,
        image_mapgross = $('image_mapgross');
        image_mapgross.onload = middleMap;
        image_mapgross.src = url;
        map_container.style.cssText = "display:block;left:10px;top:" + top + "px;";

        Event.stop(event);
        //Event.observe(map_container, 'click', stopEvent);
}
```

in `IE` the function `middleMap` is never called.

```
function middleMap() {

    var map_container = $('map_container');
    middle(map_container);
}
```

Comment: check out this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/198892/img-onload-doesnt-work-well-in-ie7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in IE if i set the source like this

```
image_mapgross.setAttribute("src", url);
```

then it works.

Answer (score 0):

use writeAttribute() method to set attributes with prototype

```
 $('image_mapgross').writeAttribute('src', url);
```

OLD:
you need to get a DOM element first

```
image_mapgross = $('image_mapgross').get(); //or  $('image_mapgross')[0]
```

if you want to set it events and properties using dot notation

```
image_mapgross.onload = middleMap;
image_mapgross.src = url;
```

Comment: the function ´$('image_mapgross')´ actually returns the extended DOM element.

Comment: ok, I see you are using prototype framework, please tag your question accordingly